# i cannot set the title for my navigationBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

here's my problem. i couldn't set the name for my navigationBar.. below are some i have tried but to no avail.

```
- (void)viewDidLload {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.title = @"Food"; 
}

- (void)viewDidLload {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.setTitle:@"Food"]; 
}

- (void)viewDidLload {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
  myTableViewController = @"Food"; 
}
```

any kind soul?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming this code is exactly like it is in your project, you mispelled the method name.  Try this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.title = @"Food";
}
```

Also, the last two examples are just plain wrong.

Comment: it still doesnt load.. is it because it cannot capture the viewcontroller?

Comment: Are you saying the view controller isn't being loaded?  What do you mean by "capture the viewcontroller"?

Comment: it is loaded.. but when i go to that page, the name of the navigation bar did not change.. so i was wondering it didn't capture the name for the viewcontroller.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have the navigation bar as a referencing outlet in IB, name with navBar or what ever you like, then in the code just add the line:
[[navBar topItem] setTitle:@"title with code"];